# jquery - show/hide div based on multiple selections

Tags: php, jquery

I have a (php/html/jquery/css) page where i'm displaying tags at the top (e.g. green, white, fruit, vegetable)

On the page I have divs marked appropriately with classes:

```
<div class="green fruit">apple</div>
<div class="green vegetable">broccoli</div>
```

etc.

I'd like to show/hide divs based on which tags have been toggled show/hide.

By default everything is shown. Clicking a tag at the top will toggle the corresponding divs.

The tricky part is to show divs if any of its classes are toggled to 'show' and hide if *all* of its classes are toggled to hide.

I'm probably making this harder than it needs to be. Thanks for your advice!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that you're using buttons to toggle the tags:

```
<button class="tag" id="toggle-fruit">Fruit</button>
<button class="tag" id="toggle-green">Fruit</button>
<button class="tag" id="toggle-vegetable">Fruit</button>
...
```

This should work:

```
var divCollection = $('div'),

    // Gather all tags (store in array):
    tags = $.map(divCollection, function(){
        return this.className.split(' ');  
    }),

    // Object to store enabled tags:
    enabledTags = {};

toggleTags();

$('button.tag').click(function(){

    var tag = this.id.split('-')[1];

    enabledTags[tag] = !enabledTags[tag];

    $(this).toggleClass('toggled'); // Maybe add some CSS?

    toggleTags();

});

function toggleTags() {

    // Hide all divs, then show those that have at least one
    // tag present in the enabledTags object.
    divCollection.hide().filter(function(){

        // Return true if one of classes is found in enabledTags
        return !!$.grep(this.className.split(' '), function(){
            return enabledTags[this];
        }).length;

    }).show();
}
```

See demo: **http://jsbin.com/omota**

Answer (score 1):

If you first hide, and then show, it should do the trick.

```
$('#my_divs div').hide();

var tags = ['fruit', 'orange'];
for(var k in tags){
    $('#my_divs div.' + tags[k]).show();
}
```

Comment: A nice, elegant solution. I kicked myself when I saw this. Thanks